# Git : Moving commit diverges branches

Tags: git

I have a repo with a master branch of 4 commits:

1-2-3-4 (HEAD → master)

Then I created a new branch (b2) and made the fifth commit, I merged b2 to master. `$ git merge b2` and I got this log :

1-2-3-4-5(HEAD → master, b2)

Now I wanna change the order of commit 2 so I made `$ git rebase -i HEAD~5`, and I got this log :

1-3-4-2-5 (HEAD → master) 
  \
2-3-4-5 (b2)

Two diverge branches.

And the result I want is :

1-3-4-2-5 (HEAD → master, b2)

Comment: It sounds like you just want to move the current `b2` branch to point at `master`?

Comment: I'm new with git so I don't really understand your question. :/

Comment: It looks to me like the difference between what you want and what you currently have is that `b2` is pointing at the `5` in the `2-3-4-5` history, while `master` points to the `5` in the `1-3-4-2-5`, which is where you want `b2` to point. So if you can move the `b2` branch to point at the same commit as your `master` is currently pointing, it will be what you want. Correct?

Comment: You literally cannot change any existing commit, so Git does not try. Instead, when using rebase to "move" commits, Git just makes *all new* commits. The old ones still exist. Anyone still using the old ones ... well, is still using the old ones. So that's what you're seeing.

Comment: Hummm Thaaank you, now I got it. so since changing a commit is impossible and  when using rebase to "move" commits, Git just makes all new commits. All I have to do is to make b2 point at master, Just like @xdhmoore said.

Comment: Now please please @xdhmoore how do i make b2 point at master.

Comment: The accepted answer looks good to me.

Comment: yes, I saw it after your comment. thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to force b2 to where master is. If you are on master at the moment:

```
git branch -f b2
```

That will do.

Comment: Note that this will cause you to lose history for the current location of `b2`. If you need that for some reason, create a new branch at the current location of `b2` before moving `b2` with the above command.

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
git checkout b2
git reset --hard master
```